# setting timeout for recv fcn of a UDP socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp, posix

I send a UDP packet by `sendto`, then receive the answer by `recv`.if `recv` does not receive the reply, the program does not proceed. However, the udp packet might be lost, or for some reason, the packet may not be delivered, so that the program gets stuck on `recv` line. I wonder how is it possible to set a timeout for `recv` if nopacket arrives in ,e.g., a minute, then skip that line and proceed the code?

I am not pasting the full code since it is a generic `udp` code and my question is related to the only `recv`. For the final note, the development environment is linux.

```
unsigned long  buf[maxlen];
struct protoent *proto;     //
struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
int s;  // socket
memset( &server_addr, 0, sizeof( server_addr ));
server_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(hostname);
sendto(s,msg,sizeof(msg),0,(struct sockaddr *)&server_addr,sizeof(server_addr));

recv(s,buf,sizeof(buf),0);
```

Comment: Make the socket non-blocking? Or use e.g. [`select`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/select.html) for polling? And of course there's the `MSG_DONTWAIT` flag for `recv` (which is a Linux specific extension).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `poll` or `select` or something similar:

```
struct pollfd fd;
int res;

fd.fd = s;
fd.events = POLLIN;
res = poll(&fd, 1, 1000); // 1000 ms timeout

if (res == 0)
{
    // timeout
}
else if (res == -1)
{
    // error
}
else
{
    // implies (fd.revents & POLLIN) != 0
    recv(s,buf,sizeof(buf),0); // we can read ...
}
```

Answer (score 12):

How to set timeout for UDP socket in Linux:

```
#include <sys/time.h>

struct timeval timeout={2,0}; //set timeout for 2 seconds

/* set receive UDP message timeout */

setsockopt(fd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_RCVTIMEO,(char*)&timeout,sizeof(struct timeval));

/* Receive UDP message */
int recvlen = recvfrom(fd, buf, BUFSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remaddr, &slen);
if (recvlen >= 0) {
    //Message Received
}
else{
    //Message Receive Timeout or other error
}
```

Comment: A return value of -1 could indicate lots of things other than a timeout. It Is essential to check the value of `errno` for `EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK` to determine whether a timeout happened.

Answer (score 3):

> I wonder how is it possible to set a timeout for recv

Call `setsockopt()` with the `SO_RCVTIMEO` option.