# Exiting the recv loop after a fixed timeout

Tags: c, sockets, recv

I am using `recv` to receive a message on the socket from the server.

```
size_t b_received = 0;
char headers[2048];
while ((b_received = recv(socket_fd,
                              &headers[pos],
                              sizeof(headers) - pos - 1, 0)) > 0) {
    pos += b_received;
}
```

Sometimes, the server takes too long to send a message and my program is stuck and waiting for the next message.

Is there a way I could just end this loop if the server does not send me the next message after 5 seconds?

Comment: You can do that by using one of  the IO multiplexing `select()`/`poll()`/`epoll()` functions instead of unconditionally reading from `socket_fd`.Those also give you the timeout you need ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setting timeout for recv fcn of a UDP socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163260/setting-timeout-for-recv-fcn-of-a-udp-socket)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [setsockopt](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setsockopt) function to set a timeout on receive operations:

```
// LINUX
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = timeout_in_seconds;
tv.tv_usec = 0;
setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&tv, sizeof tv);

// WINDOWS
DWORD timeout = timeout_in_seconds * 1000;
setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&timeout, sizeof timeout);

// MAC OS X (identical to Linux)
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = timeout_in_seconds;
tv.tv_usec = 0;
setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&tv, sizeof tv);
```

Try this to stop the socket :

```
#include <sys/socket.h>

int shutdown(int socket, int how);
```

More information [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/shutdown)

Comment: What is the difference between `close` and `shutdown`?

Comment: Generally the difference between close() andshutdown() is: close() closes the socket id for the process but the connection is still opened if another process shares this socket id. ... shutdown() breaks the connection for all processes sharing the socket id.

Comment: Is there a way to register a callback when a timeout is being called? Is there a way to know the exit was because of a timeout or a normal exit?

Comment: Sorry Amanda. I didn't experience that for now. I gonna answer back If I found the answers to your questions. Thank you for your interest.